# how to debug pthread_create() function in c++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, debugging, gdb

I'm reading some codes written in C++, in the main.cc, there are following:

```
pthread_t      sense;
void* sense_callback( void *v )
pthread_create( &sense, NULL, sense_callback  , &s); // start listening
```

I like to use the debug to see how the code run and to follow the logic in  the code when I read someone else's code, now I have no idea how should I step into this pthread_create function to see the logic flow in it. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and this is also a problem for me, since I'm new to linux. Could anyone give me any clue about how should I step into the pthread_create function to see the logic flow in this program?

Comment: pthread_create() is a C library function. There's nothing to step into. Of course, installing the debug C library package would allow one to do that, but there's nothing to see there. If you want to debug `sense_callback()`, set a breakpoint on it, and execute the code.

Comment: I open a terminal to run the start script. The script is written in python, and it will open several thread, each thread would run from the  main.cc which contains the pthread_create function, while sense_callback() is in another .cc file. In the start script I let it print the thread pid, then I use "sudo gdb -tui" to  attach  to one of the thread which run from the main.cc. Here, I don't know how to step into the pthread_create function, and also don't know how to set breakpoint on sense_callback, because I can only set breakpoint in the main.cc and where I could step into from the main.cc.

Comment: As I explained, pthread_create is a library function. What do you expect to accomplish by stepping inside it?

Comment: I mean step into the sense_callback, since sense_callback is in another .cc file, so I don't know how to set breakpoint on it. I just know how to set breakpoint in main.cc and all the files that could be stepped into from main.cc.

Comment: Read gdb's manual which explains how to set breakpoints. There are at least two ways to do it: by function name, or by source file+line number.

Comment: Wow, there are ways to set breakpoint by filename+function name, thank you so much! I can go to the sense_callback now, but the problem is the thread always exits suddenly before reaching any return in this function, and gives information like this "[Thread 0x7f32c5180700 (LWP 29032) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 26307) exited normally]". Is it because I use "n" to debug every sentence one by one? Is there any way to fix this problem so that I can go through the function from the beginning to the end?